# select within selected query?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table in mysql with account_follow name.

follower and followed point to user ID.

when follower field point to followed field that means user, followed a person with specific ID, when follower point to followed and followed point to follower that means between follower and followed is a friendship. my problem is how can i select follower's friend (follower field) with this Architecture, for example i wanna select a follower and get friends, is it posible in Query? or i must solve this in php (i shouldn't use)?

[image]

example :

- 1 and 2 are friend.
- 2 followed 1 but are not friend.
- 1 and 3 are friend.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow your question.

Comment: follower followed require follow followed follower followed ... what??

Comment: Please, clarify your question... it's too obfuscated.

Comment: I was going to downvote this, but it's actually quite funny the more you read it.

Comment: please be clear with your questions. Consider commenting the bits of your question which are names of fields. otherwise it's quite confusing

Comment: sorry guys! let me correct my question.

Comment: i edited question, is it clear now?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly...

Regardless, you can get a comma delimited list of "followed" by user id. I assume you are querying based on user id.

```
FollowedList = Convert(varchar(50),replace( 
  (SELECT distinct followed as [data()] 
  FROM account_follow a
  WHERE a.follower = b.user_id
  ORDER BY follower_id for xml path ('') ), ' ', ',') )
```

This is a subquery--therefore you would select FollowedList in your main query that joins this table with your main table, which is referred to in this query as "b".

If the list is going to be super long, you will likely need to convert it to more than just a varchar(50).

Comment: tnx Devin for your attention and time.